# After Bounty, my question did not get a satisfactory answer. What next?

Tags: support, bounties, expired-bounty

I am really confused about this. My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806709/application-is-using-java-6-instead-of-7-in-mac-osx) didn't get much attention even after offering the bounty.

What will happen to my bounty now? Will I be getting it back or is there any way to increase its expiration time?

What I can do?

Comment: You won't get your bounty back. It did it's work already, your question got attention. The answer there is *really* detailed, someone went to a lot of trouble. And *4 answers* is quite a lot, tbh. I'm sorry you didn't get a satisfactory answer; those are, unfortunately, never guaranteed.

Comment: You could put another bounty, although you have one really detailed answer. I dont think you will get any answers more detailed than that.

Comment: if you didn't get a satisfactory answer, maybe you're not asking the right question

Comment: If you didn't find Uwe's answer satisfactory, you should really let him know why (he wrote an exceptionally detailed answer and appeared to answer all your questions in the comments)

Comment: Wow, I wish I could elicit answers that detailed.  I'm amazed that that isn't enough information for you.

Comment: one comment: from the outside (I'm no expert on the topic of your question), but it appears as though you are asking follow up questions (as comments) to the detailed answer provided - if that is the case, consider whether they are clarifications, or perhaps new questions. The Q and the A should both be limited to one problem at a time, as far as possible. In short: did he help you solve the problem you described in your question?

Comment: Interestingly, given the flood of upvotes for Uwe's answers after you posted this question (something like 14 between the two answers currently), you've actually awarded him far more rep than the worth of your original bounty. Perhaps we should assume that was your intention all along :-)

Comment: In a similar situation, I awarded the bounty to what appeared to me to be the best attempt at an answer. That rewards attention and effort.

Comment: Well thanks a lot for the reply. Sorry I just didnt noticed there is a similar question. Firstly let me clarify I am asking a very practical question over there. I didnt much care about the bounty (it can be earned). Uwe is quite close but he its not the actual solution to it, I am discussing with him and he is really helping me out. I asked this question to know whether we can extend the time limit of the bounty or what will actually happen if i need more attention to my question. But now i got it if u need more attention post it on META :P

Comment: @LanceRoberts thnx for a proper edit :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> My question didn't got much attention even after offering the bounty.

You've got four answers, and at least [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15271448/643383) shows a great deal of thought and effort. Perhaps it's not a *perfect* answer from your point of view, but it's a darn good answer and it looks like it was added during the bounty period.

A bounty is not a guarantee of the answer that you're looking for, it's just a way to sweeten the deal and attract some attention. It seems to have worked in this case just the way it's meant to. If you want even more attention for your question, you can always offer another (possibly larger) bounty later.

So, just award the bounty to the most deserving answer (the choice seems pretty obvious). Offer another bounty if you really think that someone might write an even better answer than the ones you've gotten already. Perhaps a better option, though, would be to think carefully about the points that you still don't understand, and then write one or more new questions that covers those points specifically.

Comment: this is what I was really looking for. Thanks for the reply. May be I frame it in a wrong way thats why you marked it a duplicate but my whole intention for asking was to know what should I do if I think that this is not the best answer. Thnx for your help. BDW have a look at bounty question suggest me something over there if possible :P

Answer (score 3):

Not much you can do I'm afraid.

The bounty is already taken out of your Rep when you first choose to place a bounty, you don't get that back.

You *could* place another bounty on it to get it more exposure, although It's unlikely you'll get anything better though because if it didn't get attention the first time around it's unlikely to get attention again, sadly.

Bounties are just a way to increase the exposure of that question, it's not a guarantee that you'll get a perfect answer. You've given the question some decent promotion and it didn't get you what you need, so unfortunately there's not much you can do. There is no guaranteed way to make your question get an answer you like.